# On upsert with Mongo node driver, did it insert or update?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'm using Mongo's native node driver. For an upsert like:

```
collection.update(query, setData, { upsert: true }, callback);
```

Is there a way to determine if the upsert did an insert or an update? With Mongo shell you can get back `WriteResult.nUpserted` to determine this, but I'm unsure how to get that info back from the node native driver.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/WriteResult/#WriteResult.nUpserted

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find out by checking the third argument passed to your callback:

```
collection.update(query, setData, {upsert: true}, function(err, nAffected, raw) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.dir(raw);
  // raw will contain updatedExisting and the inserted item _id (if applicable)
});
```